# Scrubbing effect like music app to change value

Tags: ios, touch

I have a blank, transparent button which, when I drag left and right, and up and down, want a number to get incremented and decremented depending on how far away from the button the finger is.

Quite like the way the music app on the iPhone has the scrubbing feature, where you can get a more precise value?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are wanting to do and post some code so people can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require you to create a custom control heavily relying on gesture recognizers. I would advise you to search more on this topic.

Also, take a look here - http://oleb.net/blog/2011/01/obslider-a-uislider-subclass-with-variable-scrubbing-speed/

Comment: Thing is, I want to achieve this without using a slider. Sliding my finger across blank space (or a transparent button), rather.

Comment: @omariskamal There is no need to use any UI element at all - you can add `UIGestureRecognizer` to any `UIView`. You can refer to method `- (BOOL) continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` in the tutorial to understand how touch tracking is implemented.